# SSRS Report DateTime Parameters Do Not Support Milliseconds - Previews Correctly in Visual Studio But No Records in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, parameters

I developed an SSRS report that uses a datetime parameter and when previewing this report in Visual Studio it works correctly but once deployed to SSRS it displays no records for any date selected.

I have found that SSRS truncates a datetime parameter so if the value in the database is `2021-08-19 07:49:17.977` it is changed to `2021-08-19 07:49:17` losing the milliseconds.

If I change some of the records in the database to be `2021-08-19 07:49:17.000` then it works and those records appear.

Is there any way to stop SSRS from shaving off the milliseconds on datetime parameters as this makes it impossible to match up accurately as it is comparing `2021-08-19 07:49:17` to `2021-08-19 07:49:17.977` so finding no records.

A workaround could be to use the format command to convert the datetime field to text without milliseconds and then back to a datetime field again, or subtract the millisecond part but this is not ideal and with millions of rows will impact speed and performance.

e.g. Change this

```
FD.ILRReturnDate = @ILRReturnDate
```

To this:

```
DATEADD ( MS, - DATEPART( MS, FD.ILRReturnDate ), FD.ILRReturnDate ) = @ILRReturnDate
```

Is this a known issue or bug? I have already searched and did not find anything really relevant.

Thanks
Robin

Comment: I'm going to ask a "dumb" question here, but why are you asking your users to enter a date and time value that is accurate to 1/300th of a second?

Comment: It is not a value they enter. One SQL query populates the possible dates from that table and another is the SQL for the main report that displays the detail for the selected date but due to the truncation of milliseconds even though it is the same field in both cases it doesn't match up.

Comment: Try using a string type instead that is in an unambiguous format (`yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm` for example).

Comment: What is the format of the fields, from memory I had a similar issues a few years ago but it came down to the field format was excluding the milliseconds.  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:fff was the format I used I think.

Comment: `between` and `>= and <=` are no good?

Comment: The field in the database is DATETIME and the parameter is set as DATETIME and the field I am matching on is the same field (same field used for populating parameter and in main query). If I output the parameter value I can see it has cut off the milliseconds. If I switch the parameter to a string then I get conversion errors but I suppose I could get around that also with the format command but it would be another workaround. The software that generates this data has just started adding milliseconds to the DATETIME field and led to none of the reports now working due to this issue.

Comment: Thanks I could specify a range but then I would still need to manipulate the date to remove miliseconds and then add a second and subtract 1 millisecond to get `2021-08-19 07:49:17.999` I think. I am extracting millions of rows so any conversions are costly. I think datetime manipulation is more efficient than formatting to string and back to date but neither is ideal and shouldn't be necessary if SSRS correctly supported DATETIME fields without truncation.

Comment: `2021-08-19 07:49:17.999` is not a valid or possible datetime. Know your datatypes and their domains (and precisions). Don't assume and test the edge conditions.

Comment: It looks like the string conversion is the most popular workaround for this issue.

Comment: String conversion ended up too slow for millions of records so in the end I had to amend the source data to strip out the milliseconds from the datetime field using code I posted above. It's a shame the bug exists but is lucky I am able to modify the source data to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a limitation of SSRS/PBRS and it does not handle date/time fields correctly (fully) so if your main data source and parameter data source both reference the same field which contains milliseconds then it will fail to match any records even though it works as expected when previewed in Visual Studio.

As the table contains millions of records, string conversions proved to costly from a performace point of view. DateTime manipulations were fastest:

What proved quickest was to truncate the milliseconds from all records in the table:

```
UPDATE TableWithDateField
SET
    TheDateField = DATEADD ( MS, - DATEPART( MS, TheDateField ), TheDateField )
```

The second quickest option was to truncate the milliseconds at runtime (such as if you are not able to amend the table data):

```
WHERE
    DATEADD ( MS, - DATEPART( MS, TheDateField ), TheDateField ) = @DateParameter
```

Hopefully one day this bug will be fixed and workarounds will no longer be required.